# how to get a specific tag text from a similar type of tag in XML in python?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, elementtree, eda

I have below tags as -

```
<PREAMHD>
                    <HD SOURCE="HED">Applicants:</HD>
                    <P>Fortune V Separate Account</P>
</PREAMHD>
<PREAMHD>
                    <HD SOURCE="HED">FILING DATES:</HD>
                    <P>The application was filed on September 20, 2021</P>
</PREAMHD>
```

I tried but getting all the text of P tag for every preamHD tags-

```
 if pre.findall("./PREAMHD"):
        DATES=''
        for dates in pre.findall("./PREAMHD/HD"):
            checking_date = dates.text
            print(checking_date)
            if 'DATES' in checking_date:
                print('filing')
                for dates_phd in pre.findall("./PREAMHD/P"):
                    print(dates_phd.text)
                    for para1 in dates_phd.itertext():
                        DATES += para1.replace('DATES:', '').replace('\n',' ')
                DATES = ' '.join(DATES.split())
                print(DATES)
        message_body += 'Dated:' + str(DATES)
```

How can i get the Filing dates P tag text only ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of examples (here and elsewhere) that show how to parse XML with Python. Can you show us the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [XPath Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) - in particular the `[tag='text']` syntax.

> Selects all elements that have a child named tag whose complete text content, including descendants, equals the given text.

```
>>> pre.findall('./PREAMHD[HD="FILING DATES:"]/P')
[<Element 'P' at 0x11c239540>]
>>> for p in pre.findall('./PREAMHD[HD="FILING DATES:"]/P'):
...     p.text
'The application was filed on September 20, 2021'
```

Comment: if i have something else as in place of FILING DATES, like TIME and PLACE , do i need to mention everytime different tags?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15398259/karl-thornton , getting error on the above solution -          for dates_phd in pre.findall("./PREAMB/PREAMHD[HD="DATES"]/P"):
            for para1 in dates_phd.itertext():
                DATES += para1.replace('DATES:', '').replace('\n', ' ')
        DATES = ' '.join(DATES.split())
        print(DATES)                                                                     --------------------------------------------getting : expected error on [HD="FILING DATES:"]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15398259/karl-thornton , correct now single quote worked out, can we do something for substring matching if DATES or FIling dates , search for DATES in HD tag , get the P tag text?